# Htaccess breaks css and javascripts

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?sayfa=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

i have an htaccess code like this but it breaks css, javascripts and images. something happens like this

sayfa = css

id = style.css

Comment: if i  move my css and javascript files to subfolder everything allright but i dont feel it is reliable solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest just checking if the file exists using a rewrite condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?sayfa=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

This essentially says, if the requested filename does not actually exist on disk and is not a directory that exists on disk, then try to apply the rule.

Comment: this answer is better thank u so much it is solved my all problems

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`condition`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) before that rule to confirm the request isn't for `js` or `css` files.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !(?:css|js)$
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?sayfa=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

Regex demo: https://regex101.com/r/7WPKGh/1/

The `?:` is a non-capture group. The `|` are alternations. The `$` is the end of the string.

For `jpeg`, `jpg`, `gif`, and `png`s it could be updated to:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !(?:css|js|jpe?g|png|gif)$
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?sayfa=$1&id=$2 [L]
```