# Htaccess rewrite url exclude one redirect

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?sayfa=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

i have an rewrite url like this i want to exclude one redirect so i must edit rewrite url i will show some array results for show i want to exlude what

portfolio/8 result is

```
Array ( [sayfa] => portfolio [id] => 8 )
```

portfolio/ result is

```
Array ( [sayfa] => portfolio [id] => )
```

portfolio result is

```
Array ( [sayfa] => portfolio )
```

portfolio/8/ result is

```
Array ( [sayfa] => portfolio )
```

i want to exclude last one in php or htaccess but you know i need third one. in this point i want to redirect last one to 404 in php

Comment: You have 2 user accounts?

Comment: This is the same code as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43105908/htaccess-breaks-css-and-javascripts/ and a similar username. `sayfa` is a parameter name I don't see often (just twice tonight).

Comment: ok you got me i did it because the site says you can post in only 90 minutes. if it is inappropriate i can delete the account nope

Comment: Oh, didn't know about 90 minute rule. Just thought it was strange to have the same code twice. Sometimes it a sign of a school assignment.

Comment: no it is on my language means page :) (sayfa = page) yeah i didnt know 90 minute rule too so i created new account sorry :)

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are trying to do here. What URL do you not want to redirect? You can add in additional `RewriteCond`s, might be able to pair my previous answer with this one and get a working result.

Comment: when i write portfolio to url you know parameter page = portfolio right ? when i write portfolio/8/ (slash after 8 is doing that) parameter page = portfolio too so i want to redirect the second one to 404 (if i add slash after eight some images breaking because you know im on under)